# SSMS tool bars customization

Tags: customization, ssms, ssms-2012

I'm on Windows7, SQL Server 2012 and currently I've installed *SSMS Tools Pack* (licensed) and *SSMSBoost* (community free license) plugins, both really usefull and time savers.

The issue I'm having is that each time I restart ***ssms***, usually once a week (but some days, as this morning, maybe couple of times), I need to reconfigure the visible/hidden buttons on both toolbars related to these plugins. I guess is an issue not related to the plugins but more a ***ssms*** missconfiguration. I've searched a lot trying to find where is the problem but can't find it. It's becoming really annoying to configure tools bars on each restart.

Any clue on where the problem could be? Do anyone has/had same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am developer of SSMSBoost. The reason is that we re-create the toolbar every time SSMS starts. This is due to some old issues with toolbar registration in SSMS2008. We plan to eliminate this "bad behaviour" in coming versions.

Comment: Thanks! Got an email from the SSMS ToolsPack developer, and his answer is similar to yours. Hope on next version everything is fixed. Both are amazing tools, thanks for them!

Comment: Thanks to @MladenPrajdic too, he is author of SSMS ToolsPack